# Mathematics of Putting (finding function for ball rolling on surface under gravity)

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

I was thinking up a problem today, and am unsure how to solve it.

> Let's say we have a surface modeled by $g(x,y,z) $, where $z $ is the height from the lowest point, which we will set as $z = 0$. We place a golf ball of mass $m $ at the location $(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) $ on the surface. Find the function, $f$, which gives you the location of the ball at a specified time, where the ball is subject to a gravitational field.

**thoughts:**

My idea was that we cold possibly use Lagrange Multipliers and/or the Euler equation, however I'm unsure how to do it if this is possible (I am very new to these concepts, and have yet to see how they relate).

As $t \to \infty $, the ball will be at rest at the location of a minimum for $g (x,y,z) $.

Comment: The question is incomplete. There won't be any motion unless there is some sort of force field. Do you mean for the ball to have mass and the surface to exist in a uniform gravitational field?

Comment: This problem will almost certainly involve setting up a system of ordinary differential equations which describe the motion of the ball, the solution of which will generally not be expressible in closed form, especially given the fact that $g(x, y, z)$ is so general.   Also, the equation must have dissipative or frictive  terms lest the ball *never* come to rest.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I'm sorry, I must have forgotten to include that part.

Comment: I guess the first thing is to figure out a good coordinate system.